# How do I one-hot encode a column for classification that has a string containing a few words?

Tags: python, classification, one-hot-encoding

I am using Python for a classification problem. I want to one-hot encode a column that has a string currently as the result. Below is an example of what I am looking for. If a row in that column has a string that contains "bleu cheese", I want to encode it as 0. For all other results, I want to encode it as 1. I don't want multiple columns. I just want to keep a single column.

```
  Dressing             Salad
0  Bleu Cheese        Spinach
1  Thick Bleu Cheese  Chicken
2  Ranch              Chicken
3  Italian            Taco
```

I want it to look like this

```
   Dressing          Salad
0  0                 Spinach
1  0                 Chicken
2  1                 Chicken
3  1                 Taco
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using `Pandas` library like so:

```
data_dressing = pd.get_dummies(data['dressing'])
```

Or using `Series` something like this:

```
data['dressing'] = pd.Series([1 if 'bleu cheese' in i else 0
                            for i in data['dressing']], index=data.index)
```